# Unslider issue with height and width

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Using unslider.com responsive slider I got an issue.

Code index.html
pastebin.com/5699b3DL

[image: image 1]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/18755532828664328042.png))</sub>

[image: image 2]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/97361034166595739133.png))</sub>

As you can see image is not centered and its not fit to window size. And its not responsive.

Tried:
Setting paddings, margins 0px to img, ul etc
Height initial,width %,initial etc

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: can you add a snippet with relevant code?

Comment: @silviagreen I don't know what snippet is, I'm sorry

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
.unslider img { max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I have tried this with firefox editor, but only pasting this to CSS file fixed issue, strange.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using on you main site as well with those placehold.it images? Because, it seems to be the cause. When I am replacing those with proper images, with their complete urls(`http://LLLL.com/img.jpg`). It works fine.

Try that, or provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: I have put an "http://alseyon.com/wp-content/sitecontent/banners/evoo73_2484299442_ext001.jpg" And still, not responsive.

Comment: https://vid.me/Pjm0
It should show the problem with image. Mute sound, forget to do that.